# Social login in flutter

Tags: django, flutter, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement social login in my application, the front-end is built with Flutter and my backend with Django and Django rest framework.

In flutter i'm using Google_sign_in package to connect users when i get access token i send it to the backend. after this i request informations of my user from google with the access token if the user exits in Django database i return authentication token if not i create new user and i return authentication token.

My question is: is it safe or are there better ways to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It is completely safe, I used `django-allauth` library to social login and when i used it, i didnt relay on any other libs.

With the save `lib`, It supports all the leading social media and website for `auth` login.

Here you go for the docs: https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html